# jquery traversing an appended to ol/ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to traverse a ul that has been appended to before traversing like so:

```
var items = [];
$('#list').append('<li id="item_10">item 10</li>'); 
$('#list').each(function () {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    items.push(item);
});
alert(items.toString());
```

But when I alert the output I don't see the item I added. Anyone have a clue on how I can add to a list then traverse it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping over the `ul` parent. Probably want something like

```
$('#list li').each(function() {
});
```

to loop over the `li` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

What andy said.

Also consider using jQuery awesome chainability:

```
var items = [];
$('#list')
.append('<li id="item_10">item 10</li>')
.find('li')
.each(function () {
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    items.push(item);
});
alert(items.toString());
```